# JSON Object Parsing in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending JSON data to the server (in HTML/JavaScript) and trying to parse the same JSON on server (in PHP).

When the data is sent to server, I am not sure whether the Key & Value pair is received or not ? The code is not executing perfectly

Though I am on client side , I am not able to see error, because the PHP code is executing on server side and not sending any response back. Please see where am i committing mistake

in HTML/JS

```
function processJSON(str){

var res = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
var message = "'{ " + res + " }'";
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(message);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/cards-display/process_cards.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.responseText !== newName) {
                alert('Something went wrong. ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
            else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
            }
        };

        var data = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);
        xhr.send(data);

}
```

in PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($decoded); 
var_dump($data); 

foreach($decoded as $key => $value) 
{

            $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
            $sql = "UPDATE wp_assign_cards_numbers SET numbers ='".$value."' WHERE cards = '".$key."'";

            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo ' Record Updated Successfully';

            }


}
?>
```

Comment: Well the first step would be to confirm if the PHP file is indeed receiving the data in the first place. What happens when you var_dump or print_r on $data and $decoded? Also turn on error reporting and see what comes up.

Comment: Also, why use file_get_contents for your data, why not just send it in a $_POST request?

Comment: Also what's the value of `str` ? Why are you calling `JSON.parse` when you do immediately `JSON.stringify` afterwards?

Comment: that's what, i am on client side HTML page, the above PHP code is executing on backend and i am not able to see any changes happening on server side. like echo, error msg, etc, how can i check the values if i can't see any changes ?

Comment: So I guess you're not able to modify the PHP code either?

Comment: i can modify, but can't see the output..

Comment: Oh, well all you need to do is put in echo,var_dump, or print_r statements and such to see any output.

Comment: After $decoded = json_decode($data, true);
put in var_dump($decoded); and var_dump($data); and see what comes up.

Comment: I have added, where is see error now..?? i am on different html page and no response received on that page

Comment: Also, put these lines at the top of your PHP (inside the block) to turn on errors. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: added the above code in my php file and not able to see error on my html/client page

Comment: Why `message = "'{ " + res + " }'"`? And why the apostrophes? The string generated this way is not valid JSON.

Comment: @axi to convert the string to JSON format before parsing ..

Comment: How do you know that `message` is valid JSON? It is not valid JSON because of the apostrophes but even if the apostrophes are not there, `res` might contain anything.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp  , i followed this, text in this tutorial is of same format

Comment: Minor issue: if you send JSON then the `Content-Type` should be `application/json`.

Comment: The apostrophes in the tutorial you are using are the JavaScript delimiters of a string literal. They are not part of the string. You don't use a literal (i.e. a text embedded in the code) but you have the text in a variable. If the text in `str` is not a valid JSON then `JSON.parse(str)` returns `undefined` and it displays an error message in the browser's console. But your `str` is probably not a JSON. You should collect the data you want to send to the server in an Object variable then use `JSON.stringify()` to produce a valid JSON and send it.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: We can't really help you if we don't know what the value of `str` is.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the content type : `application/json` in JS.

In PHP, when you send json data, you can access It by using `$_POST`, the json decode Is already done for you.

If you still have problems try displaying the content of `$decoded` with a `var_dump($decoded)` before the foreach statement.

By the way careful with this sql statement, you are not protected against sql injections. Use something like this :

```
$safe_key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
$safe_value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

Then use these safe variable in your SQL statement.
Hope this can help you ?

Comment: *"In PHP, when you send json data, you can access It by using $_POST, the json decode Is already done for you."* -- completely wrong.

Comment: axiac  I have never specified json_decode() in my scripts and I have always used json data send with Ajax and retrieved the content directly using $_POST, Can you explain ?

Comment: I don't use any framework, perhaps Jquery but sometimes I use JavaScript and do not need to decode the json, it's already avaible in an associative Array in $_POST

Comment: jQuery and JavaScript run in browser. `$_POST` is on the server, in PHP. PHP runs on the server and it doesn't care about what happens in the browser. In fact, there is no need to be a browser at the other end.

Comment: I know this, what I'm trying to say is that perhaps Jquery or JavaScript xhr request sends the data encoded and php decodes It and renders it available in an associative array $_POST. I have Never used json_decode to retrieve data sent in json. But I have used json_encode to reply to the client. And all my sites work perfectly fine